# C++ inheritance design: avoid member duplication

Tags: c++, inheritance

Let's assume that one has two `C++` classes that support read-only and write-only operations on a file descriptor respectively.

```cpp
class ReadFd {
 public:
  ssize_t read( /* */ ) {
    // read from file_descriptor_
  }
 protected:
  int file_descriptor_;
};

class WriteFd {
 public:
  ssize_t write(/* */) {
    // write to file_descriptor_
  }
 protected:
  int file_descriptor_;
};
```

Now suppose one would like to define a class `ReadWriteFd` that supports both read and write operations.

My question is how to design such read-write class to avoid code duplication?

I cannot inherit from both `ReadFd` and `WriteFd` because obviously I need just one `file_descriptor_`. The real situation that I encountered a bit more complicated but the concept here reflects it rather close.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a third class, base to both `ReadFd` and `WriteFd`, whose only purpose is to contain the descriptor variable (and possibly other things common to both reading and writing).

Comment: the virtual method with base implementation (something like `return 0`) for read and write themselves? is it a good thing?

Comment: I have the same question here. Can we avoid the virtual call please? Would you be so kind as to elaborate a bit?

Comment: @TruLa No `virtual` is needed, unless you want to be able to override the functions in the child-classes (which for this case is a bad idea IMO).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I am really sorry but I'm not 100% confident that I understood you correct. Do you suggest that I should have `class Base { protected: int file_descriptor_ }` and `class ReadFd : public Base {}`, `class WriteFd : public Base {}`? Then how should I orginize `class ReadWriteFd`. I would like to have just one descriptor that I can read/write from/to?

Answer (score 2):

Create a new base class called `class Fd` which contains the file descriptor. `class ReadFd` & `WriteFd` can both inherit from it with an `is-a` relationship. Your   `ReadWriteFd` can inherit from these 2 classes. Just remember that you will have to solve the [diamond multiple inheritance problem](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/multiple-inheritance-in-c-and-the-diamond-problem-7c12a9ddbbec).

Here is an example UML:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As [OO Principals](https://blog.bryanbibat.net/2009/08/10/object-oriented-principles/) state:

Encapsulate what varies. – can be rephrased as “Identify the aspects of your application that vary and separate them from what stays the same.” For those aspects that don’t change, we leave them as they are. Of course, we can’t just throw away those parts that vary; the former still needs to interact with them in order for the system to work.
In your particular case you can create a base class with common data and interfaces.